# Windows 8.1 on MBA (Mid 2013) - Wifi intermittent dropouts until adapter is disabled/enabled

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8.1, macbook-air

I'm carrying my MacBook Air (Mid 2013) between the office and home (running Windows 8.1 via Bootcamp).

In the office, the MBA is on Ethernet via an USB3 to Ethernet adapter and at home I'm using Wifi. Whenever I come home from the office and my MBA connects to Wifi, I have intermittent Wifi dropouts (it appears they are exactly 10s apart, i.e. if I ping the local router, access point or any other destination, I have one lost packet every 10 seconds). Once I go to the adapter settings, disable and then enable the adapter, everything works flawlessly thereafter with no more dropouts (until I come back home from the office the next day).

The MBA uses a Broadcom 802.11ac Network Adapter and I'm using the standard driver (v6.30.223.75).

Any idea what may be causing this and how this could be fixed permanently?

Answer (score 0):

what kind of wireless router do you have at home?, did you update the firmware of it lately?
11ac is pretty new, so can you check if there is a newer driver for the 11ac wireless card in your mba?
either report the problem to broadcom and see if they have a fix for it, or to your router manufactorer (they can also help if the problem is related to their hardware)

FYI: do wireless work in OS X?

and would be nice to give us moar info, what is the model number of the macbook and the wireless chipset?, what manufacturer/model is the wireless router?

Comment: The wifi access points are Unifi AP's (contacted vendor, no advise on this issue). There are no new drivers for the MBA's wifi NIC. MBA model is MD761LL/A